# get userData of SKSpriteNode using the scene editor

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, user-data

I set the userData of my SKSpriteNode in the scene editor:

[image]

Then I tried to get it, using:

```
let sprite:SKSpriteNode = self.childNode(withName: "sprite") as? SKSpriteNode
let numero:Int = sprite.userdata?.valueForKey("numero") as! Int
```

But I got nil value : "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

I also tried to init the userData with:

```
sprite.userData? = NSMutableDictionary()
```

But same result...

Comment: did you save the scene editor?

Comment: by which @Knight0fDragon means to say that there's a reasonably well known set of anomalies in the Scene Editors within Xcode - that they don't autosave like just about everything else in Xcode does. Saving the scene, whilst in the scene editor (for some properties) propagates them out into storage in a way that they work as intended... sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably also your sprite is nil:

try to search your sprite with the optional binding (if let) and the "//" before sprite.

```
if let sprite = self.childNode(withName: "//sprite") as? SKSpriteNode {
       let numero:Int = sprite.userdata?.valueForKey("numero") as! Int
} else {
   print("I cannot find sprite..")
}
```

It performs a recursive search from its current position. 
Check the API reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW74).